# How to request an array to http get parameters with a for?

Tags: python, arrays, http, post, get

Below is my code to your view:

```
import warnings
import contextlib
import json
import requests
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning


old_merge_environment_settings = requests.Session.merge_environment_settings

@contextlib.contextmanager
def no_ssl_verification():
    opened_adapters = set()

    def merge_environment_settings(self, url, proxies, stream, verify, cert):
        # Verification happens only once per connection so we need to close
        # all the opened adapters once we're done. Otherwise, the effects of
        # verify=False persist beyond the end of this context manager.
        opened_adapters.add(self.get_adapter(url))

        settings = old_merge_environment_settings(self, url, proxies, stream, verify, cert)
        settings['verify'] = False

        return settings

    requests.Session.merge_environment_settings = merge_environment_settings

    try:
        with warnings.catch_warnings():
            warnings.simplefilter('ignore', InsecureRequestWarning)
            yield
    finally:
        requests.Session.merge_environment_settings = old_merge_environment_settings

        for adapter in opened_adapters:
            try:
                adapter.close()
            except:
                pass

with no_ssl_verification():
    ##350014,166545
    payload = {'key1': '350014', 'key2': '166545'}
   resp = requests.get('https://rhconnect.marcopolo.com.br/api/workers/data_employee/company/1/badge/params', params=payload, verify=False, headers={'Authorization': 'Token +++++private++++', 'content-type': 'application/json'})
print(resp.status_code)
    print(resp.status_code)
    j = resp.json()
    ##print(j)
    jprint(resp.json())
```

how can I do a while or a for to send a list of personal id numbers and get a JSON result to witch one?
I tried pasting some parametres but it does not work, produce some errors...

I got this follow error:

> JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

if i put:

```
 resp = requests.get('https://rhconnect.marcopolo.com.br/api/workers/data_employee/company/1/badge/350014',
```

with a single number, it works.
here the follow json:

```
200
[
    {
        "DT_INI_VIG_invalidez": null,
        "DT_fim_VIG_invalidez": null,
        "MODULO": "APOIO",
        "chapa": 350014,
    }
]
```

Comment: why don't you show full error? We can't run code to see error. And we can't read in your mind - so your question is useless.

Comment: now about `for item in [350014,166545]: payload = {"key": item}`

Comment: I'm sorry I will put it here

Comment: if you get error with JSON then you should use `print(resp.text)` to see what you get - probably you get HTML with warning that you used wrong command.

Comment: you have to use `/company/1/badge/" + str(params) ` instead of `/company/1/badge/params"` or you `/company/1/badge/{}".format(params)`  or in newest Python `f-string `f"/company/1/badge/{params}". Your current url sends word `"params"` instead of number

Comment: i used  `for item in [350014,166545, 342777]: payload = item` and `resp = requests.get('https://rhconnect.marcopolo.com.br/api/workers/data_employee/company/1/badge/'+ str(payload),` but it just returns the last number 342777, can you help me?

Comment: standard rule: if you have many elements then you have to keep them on list.

Comment: see `all_results.append(resp.json())` in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add number to url manually

```
"https://rhconnect.marcopolo.com.br/api/workers/data_employee/company/1/badge/" + str(params)
```

or

```
"https://rhconnect.marcopolo.com.br/api/workers/data_employee/company/1/badge/{}".format(params)
```

or using f-string in Python 3.6+

```
f"https://rhconnect.marcopolo.com.br/api/workers/data_employee/company/1/badge/{params}"
```

Using `params=params` will not add numer to url this way but `?key1=350014&key2=166545`

You can see url used by request using

```
    print(resp.request.url)
```

Now you can run in loop

```
all_results = []

for number in [350014, 166545]:
    url = 'https://rhconnect.marcopolo.com.br/api/workers/data_employee/company/1/badge/{}'.format(number)
    resp = requests.get(url, verify=False, headers={'Authorization': 'Token +++++private++++', 'content-type': 'application/json'})

    #print(resp.request.url)
    print(resp.status_code)
    print(resp.json())

    # keep result on list
    all_results.append(resp.json())
```

---

**BTW:** If you get error then you should check what you get

```
print(resp.text)
```

Maybe you get HTML with information or warning

Comment: uauuuu!! you are amazing!!! I really thank you for your effort!!

Comment: I just get some warnings but its okay at all. **: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified
  InsecureRequestWarning)**

Comment: take off message of warnings >>> import urllib3
>>> urllib3.disable_warnings()